# Bring DB values into Form to edit them

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

My purpose here is to bring the DB values into the form, so that the user is able to edit them. However, the values are not being displayed in the form. Here is my code. Thank you!

```
$(".btnEditarUsuario").on("click", function(){
var idUsuario = $(this).attr("idUsuario");
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);

$.ajax({
    url:"ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta){
        console.log("respuesta", respuesta);
        $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta["nombre"]);
        $("#editarUsuario").val(respuesta["usuario"]);
  $("#editarRol").html(respuesta["rol"]);
}
 });
})


<?php

    require "../controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
    require "../modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";

    class AjaxUsuarios{
        public $idUsuario;
        public function ajaxEditarUsuario(){
        $item = "id";
        $valor = $this->idUsuario;
        $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["idUsuario"])){
        $editar = new AjaxUsuarios();
        $editar -> idUsuario = $_POST["idUsuario"];
        $editar -> ajaxEditarUsuario();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post the code as code/text, _not_ as image. Also it would be favorable if you could include more information about your debugging results. _"not being shown"_ is a bit broad when a database, an ajax call etc. are involved.

Comment: Code changed! :)

Comment: TRY to change -> dataType: "json", to -> dataType: "JSON"

Comment: Did so, but nothing happened :(

Comment: Perhaps, the problem is in your php file. Are you sure that it returns valid data or does it return data?

Comment: That's the problem. The function(respuesta) is returning anything.

Comment: Since you've tracked down the problem to `ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios` not returning anything check if you get into `if(isset($_POST["idUsuario"]))`, check the val for `$_POST["idUsuario"]`, then get into the method `ctrMostrarUsuarios` to check everything possible there. Start [debugging](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae)!